# How to manually sign into WiFi network?

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop

I'm connecting to a WiFi network that I know show ask me for the username and password in the web browser when I go to access the internet. However it's not doing that when I go into my web browser. I'm sometimes presented with the sign in prompt right when I connect to the network, but not always.

How do I go to the sign in screen?

Comment: WiFi's usually ask for a passphrase only. Do you mean a hotspot?

Comment: I think he's talking about a captive portal.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a hotspot, not a usual password-protected network. If, once you connect, it doesn't tell you to sign in but you know you must pass the registration for the further access to internet, open any internet page... and it will redirect you to the signing screen, if the network is really protected.